# PyCharm: How to Perform Multi-Line Rename?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm and **need to perform a multi-line rename** in my code.
Specifically, I want to add a prefix, such as `self.`, to the beginning of multiple lines at once in a Python class. Manually editing each line can be time-consuming, so I'm looking for a more efficient way to achieve this in PyCharm. **What are the steps or hotkeys to perform a multi-line rename in PyCharm?**

Example:

```
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("Title")

        menu = tk.Menu(root)
        root.config(menu=menu)

        file_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=False)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=open_file)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=save_file)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=on_closing)

        edit_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=False)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit_menu)
        edit_menu.add_command(label="Clear", command=clear_text)

        text = tk.Text(root)
        text.pack()

        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
        root.mainloop()
```

What I Tried:
I tried manually clicking at the beginning of each line and pressing Alt to add self. to the beginning of multiple lines. However, this method proved to be time-consuming and inefficient for a larger codebase.

Expectation:
I was expecting to find a more efficient way to perform a multi-line rename in PyCharm, such as adding a prefix (e.g., self.) to multiple lines in a Python class.

Comment: Either use mouse-middle-click'n'drag or [Alt]+left-mouse-click to place multiple cursors regardless of the text. To me [Alt]+[J] became second nature. For each use it finds the next occurence of a selected text snippet and adds another cursor there.

Comment: This sounds more like Find/Replace. Rename is for renaming variables.

Comment: @CodeNStuff Thank you mouse mouse-middle-click'n'drag was what I need.

Comment: @Barmar: Mea culpa.

Answer (score 0):

Select the lines you want to replace in with the mouse.

Then use <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd-r</kbd> on Mac) to perform a Find/Replace; when there's a selection, this defaults to only operating within that block of lines.

Fill in the search string and the replacement fields. All the matches will be highlighted. You can then use the **Replace** button to replace them one by one (which you can use to skip some if necessary), or **Replace All** to replace all at once.